# Input click remove disabled attribute and place cursor at end of input

Tags: jquery, input, field

I am trying to figure out how to put the cursor to the end when input is clicked because now if i click an input it just removes the disabled attribute but I still cannot type any text I need to press twice to be able to start writing some text. What solution could it be ?

By the way **1.4** jQuery is used.

JS:

```
$('.some-input-field').live('click', function () {
            var inputField = $(this).focus();
            inputField.removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: `By the way 1.4 jQuery is used.` You should *really* upgrade. That's almost 10 years out of date

Comment: It is old project. It does not depend on me.